# replacing ^ in string in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, replace

```
    var charactersGone = sen.replace(/&|!|^/g, "");
```

is the code I am trying to use, it works for the ampersand and exclamation mark but the tophat stays whether in multiples or singles.

Comment: escape \^ it perhaps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In regex, the caret symbol (`^`) matches the position before the first character in the string, so just escape it if you want a literal caret: `/&|!|\^/`

Comment: Thank you, kept seeing it done without the escape in front from examples I was finding online.